# My maps vs Google Maps Engine

Tags: google-maps, maps

I wanted to create a new map to store all my different routes I take daily:
* From Home to work
* Work to school
* school to park
... and so on.

But suddenly I had two open links:

1. https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/ "My Maps"
2. https://mapsengine.google.com/admin "Google Maps Engine"

[image]

First I thought they were related but I never arrived to modify a map created with My Maps in the Google Maps Engine and vive versa.

Somebody knows the difference of these two apps?

NOTE: All I needed was in "My Maps" app, but I certainly curious why they are kept separated from Google Maps Engine

Answer (score 0):

Google Maps Engine allows you to add data layers on the maps. Basically you can add customized visualization on the map and furthermore if you are developing an app, you can embed your map saved in gallery in the app as an API. However, Google will stop supporting Maps Engine on January 29, 2016 and has stopped accepting new projects.
My Maps has a lot of similar functionality. You can add data layers here in CSV, XLSV or KML. You can also embed the map in a website and export KML of your custom map to embed as a KML layer.
Hope this is clear enough.

Comment: So my maps and the functionality that comes with it will continue to exist?

Comment: Yeah. My Maps seems available still. You could check if there are more functionality now.